# Kohana 3 Share admin between multiple projects

Tags: php, kohana, admin, kohana-3

Is it possible to share admin area (having admin controllers,modules and views) among multiple projects. I want to design admin module having common functionality like admin user-role management, modules management etc. that will be shared with multiple projects. There can be possibility one of project may hold custom admin functionality. At the end all projects should hold admin common and custom functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Kohana forum I got answer that we could create admin section as module and override specific functions from apps.